# Numerical Conditional replacement in R

Tags: r

I have been looking for the write adjustment to my code a while now, but couldn't find one. It is probably a simple fix, but I couldn't find it. So, I would like to ask for guidance.

My sample data set is as follows:

```
   Sample 
      .     
  <25.0      
    0.6      
   2.22     
   2.23     
   2.45     
   2.65     
      .     
      .     
   17000    
   10000    
    6000    
    4000  
    2000  
    1000  
     750
```

I would like to change those that are greater than 25 to the number divided by 1000 and ignore anything not numerical (basically ignoring "<25.0" and ".") and converting back to ".", so the following result:

```
  Sample 
      .     
      .      
    0.6      
   2.22     
   2.23     
   2.45     
   2.65     
      .     
      .     
      17    
      10     
       6    
       4  
       2  
       1  
     0.75
```

As far the code, I have as follows:

```
sk$sample_1 <- sk$Sample

sk$sample_1 <- as.numeric(as.character(sk$sample_1))


#sk$sample_1[which(sk$sample_1 > 25 & !is.na(sk$sample_1)] = sk$sample_1/1000
sk$sample_1[sk$sample_1 > 25 & !is.na(sk$sample_1)] <- sk$sample_1/1000


#changing back to "."
sk$sample_1[is.na(sk$sample_1)] <- "."
```

However, I obtain the following output:

```
    Sample sample_1
1          .        .
2      <25.0        .
3        0.6      0.6
4       2.22     2.22
5       2.23     2.23
6       2.45     2.45
7       2.65     2.65
8          .        .
9          .        .
10     17000        .
11     10000        .
12      6000    6e-04
13      4000  0.00222
14      2000  0.00223
15      1000  0.00245
16       750  0.00265
```

I am sure I am coding the last portion incorrectly, but I cannot find a fix for it. Any help is much appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Comment: To keep with your logic, you could just do `sk$sample_1[sk$sample_1 > 25 & !is.na(sk$sample_1)] <- sk$sample_1[sk$sample_1 > 25 & !is.na(sk$sample_1)] /1000`. Right now, the two vectors don't have the same length.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! It made so much more sense!! Really appreciated everyone's effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do this with a little if/else action in a call to `sapply`:

```
sk$Sample_1 <- sapply(sk$Sample, function(x) {

    y <- as.numeric(x)

    if (is.na(y)) {

        NA

    } else if (y > 25) {

        y / 1000

    } else {

        y

    }

})
```

If you actually want the NAs to be `.`, you could replace the `NA` in that code with a `"."`. Just bear in mind that the whole vector will be string instead of numeric if you do that, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! The if and else will definitely come in handy later on!